# How to force NOT running the program after silently installing existing Inno Setup package

Tags: installation, inno-setup, silent-installer

I need to push a program that was packaged with Inno Setup. I'd like to just install it and be done, not start it yet. However, when using the `/silent` or `/verysilent` parameter, the program in question still runs after installation. After some searching around, I'm guessing the person who wrote the original package forgot to set `skipifsilent` in the `[Run]` section.

I've tried using `/saveinf` with the "Run this program when installation is complete" box is unchecked, and then `/loadinf` – no dice, it's not specified in that file.

What are the magic command line parameters to make this (otherwise very simple) install complete without starting the program afterwards? If there are none, is there a simple way to repackage it so it won't start after installation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to skip post-install `Run` entries from command-line, using the `.inf` file, or any other way.

All you can do is to de-compile the package, modify it (adding the `skipifsilent` flag) and re-compile.

You can use for example the [Inno Setup Unpacker](https://innounp.sourceforge.net/) or [innoextract](https://github.com/dscharrer/innoextract).

---

Of course, if the `Run` entry is associated with a task or a component, you can is command-line or `.inf` file to de-select the task/component.

See [How to install Visual Studio Code silently (without auto open when installation ends)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42582230/850848)

Comment: Unpacker won't help you if you need to get the [Code] section data.

Answer (score 0):

In your INF file under section [SETUP], add the line:
LaunchProgram=

This will bypass any launch application previously configured in the package.

Comment: There's no such parameter in Inno Setup. It might be a custom feature of your specific installer.